# Gatsby useState not updating value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm using gatsby with functional component and react useState hooks with Material UI and particularly for this problem the Dialog API to mimic the behavior on this docs: https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/ .

But the useState on openModal is not updating the value of the state, so the modal can only be closed by the Esc key.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel"
import {
  Typography,
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogActions,
  Button,
} from "@material-ui/core"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  return {
    container: {
      height: "100%",
      width: "70%",
      [theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
        width: "70%",
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
        width: "90%",
      },
    },
    carrusel: {
      height: "100%",
      width: "100%",
      maxWidth: "400px",
    },
    img: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
    },
    text: {
      color: "#000",
      padding: "25px",
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      maxWidth: "400px",
      textTransform: "uppercase",
      textAlign: "center",
    },
    modal: {
      width: "95vw",
      maxHeight: "90vh",
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center",
    },
    closeIcon: {
      height: "75px",
      width: "75px",
    },
    button: {
      backgroundColor: "#ed1c24",
      color: "#fff",
      textAlign: "center",
    },
    buttonFirst: {
      marginRight: "15px",
    },
    buttonContainer: {
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      marginTop: "25px",
      marginBottom: "75px",
    },
    link: {
      textDecoration: "none",
      color: "#fff",
    },
  }
})

export default ({ slides, text, ModalComponent }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false)

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenModal(false)
    console.log(openModal)
  }

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpenModal(true)
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.container} onClick={handleOpen}>
      <Carousel
        className={classes.carrusel}
        infiniteLoop={true}
        autoPlay
        interval={5000}
        showArrows={true}
        showThumbs={false}
        showStatus={false}
        transitionTime={750}
        showIndicators={true}
      >
        {slides.map(item => (
          <img className={classes.img} src={item} />
        ))}
      </Carousel>
      {text ? (
        <Typography noWrap className={classes.text} variant={"h4"}>
          {text}
        </Typography>
      ) : null}

      <Dialog
        onRequestClose={handleClose}
        className={classes.modal}
        open={openModal}
        onClose={handleClose}
        maxWidth={"xl"}
        fullWidth={true}
      >
        <DialogTitle>{text}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <ModalComponent slides={slides} />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions className={classes.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            className={`${classes.button} ${classes.buttonFirst}`}
            onClick={handleClose}
          >
            Cerrar
          </Button>
          <Button className={classes.button} onClick={handleClose}>
            <Link className={classes.link} to="#contact-form">
              Cotizar
            </Link>
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: setting state is an async process, you cannot `console.log` after `setOpenModal` and see the updated value

Comment: But shouldn't it close the modal when the state is updated? Because the modal is NEVER closing.

Comment: At a glance this looks right. You may want to try to simplify until you can isolate where the unexpected behavior is coming from. I'd start by removing the whole Dialog and instead just adding `<button onClick={handleClose}>Close</button>` and confirming that `openModal` is updated to `false`. If it is, you know the issue lies with the Material UI Dialog, not `setState`.